# How can I get rid of bold just for one word in the lstlisting environment?

Tags: listings, bold

I have the following Matlab code in my Latex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,escapeinside={@}{@}]   
   gamma=[1/4,3/4];  
   alpha=[1/4,3/4]; 
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But in my Latex file the variable name gamma is in bold and alpha isn't. How can I get rid of the bold for one specific variablename?

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your updated code needs `\usepackage{listings}`, but with that neither word is bold, so there is more your set-up you need to tell us about.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the language `matlab` treats `gamma` as a keyword.  You can remove that via the `deletekeywords` option:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
 \begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,escapeinside={@}{@},language=matlab,deletekeywords={gamma}]   
   gamma=[1/4,3/4];  
   alpha=[1/4,3/4]; 
 \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```